# Wordpress unexpected 'add_action'

Tags: php, wordpress, exception, wordpress-theming, hosting

I transferred my site (done with wordpress) from one hosting to another (Aruba for those who knew it).

- I then loaded the files from filezilla,
- I made the db restore,
- and modified the wp-config with the new sb parameters.

But when I try to view the site here comes this message on screen:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING) in /web/htdocs/www.**domain**.it/home/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/theme-options.php on line 1
```

I have no other clues because I didn't change the code but I just moved the folder from side to side.
What was the mistake? How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Sometimes I've run into files somehow getting corrupt after transferring via FTP. Certain weird fixes have actually worked in the past like copying the PHP into notepad, deleting and re-creating the file, and then copying back. The fact that it says on line 1 tells me that maybe the line breaks were lost in your file unless the file actually starts with that.

Comment: @JoelM you were right, I don't know why but all the files had been corrupted. I didn't notice this. Thanks for the tip!